# magento doesnt load after clearing cache when installed in wamp

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, wamp

I have Installed created a duplicate copy of my production site on windows 8. Using Wamp 2.5. When I load the site for the first time after I have put the files in www folder and the add the backed up SQL from my production site. It works fine.

But after I clear the cache the site doesnt work. Both the front end and the backend. I have configured everything correctly.

I have enabled rewrite modules as well. Dunno why this error. I need help regarding this.

Thank you.
Kaushik

Comment: Did you modified the details in local.xml file when moved to new server and also did u modified the details in core_config_data table in database?

Comment: No I have followed this guide for duplicating my production site - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUU9t2RGqMg

Answer (score 0):

changes that have to be done in database:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=”http://example.com/” WHERE path=”web/unsecure/base_url”;
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=”https://example.com/” WHERE path=”web/secure/base_url”;
```

changes that have to be made in local.xml at app/etc/local.xml at line no. 41:

```
<default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[database-username]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[database-password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[database-dbname]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
```

Modify these values in both the places and remove the cache files in var/cache folder and refresh the pages.

Comment: Actually all this is done.. The error is after removing the files from var/cache or clicking the Flush Cache in magento admin. After I do this it shows no website available. When I click on the flush cache magento the page redirects to no page available.

Thats why wondering if any setting specially to be done in wamp or windows 8 so site works fine after refreshing cache